# dll load error in python due to insufficient stack size?

Tags: python, fortran

I have a python code which imports dll's created by f2py (from fortran routines). Now the python program crashes if the arrays in fortran are too large. How do I manage with this? By increasing stack size? Or heap? I've tried to study the matter, but I still do not understand how I can increase the stack or should I use the heap instead and how I should do that..??? Python always crashes on the line where I try to import the dll, i.e., at line "import f90_routine". Someone also mentioned threads, but I do not know how to use them. Hope someone can help me!!

Comment: Are you sure this is a stack overflow problem? What makes you think it is?

Comment: please include information about the python version you're using, the Fortran and C compilers and the compilation flags which were used to produce the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that you are storing large arrays of data on the stack. This is bad design and is probably due to the way the Fortran code is implemented.

Large arrays need to be stored on the heap and dynamically allocated there.  To solve this problem you will need to understand and modify your Fortran code accordingly.

The `ALLOCATE` keyword is how you create heap allocated data in Fortran 90.  However, many compilers have options that for arrays to be allocated on the heap and that may be the most expedient route for you right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called EDITBIN shipped with Visual Studio (and maybe also the Windows SDK) which is exactly what you want. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for reference.

To check the stack size, use

```
dumpbin /headers python.exe
```

and look for "size of stack reserve" under "optional header values".

```
editbin /stack:size_in_bytes python.exe
```

Note that you will have to distribute the modified Python.exe to all people who want to run your code.

Comment: Modified Python exe sounds a rather drastic solution to the problem!

Comment: I had to do something like that on site for a customer, because pythonservice.exe (from pywin32) used a smaller stack size than Python and I had my program crashing when running as a Windows service. When hit with a stack overflow in Python, you don't always have many other options and the trick above was a life saver for me. Note that recent versions of pywin32 should have the issue fixed.

Comment: I think the OP's problem will actually be that the arrays that are stack allocated are simply too huge to make sense to be placed on a stack.

Comment: Great! Still works. Perfect as a temporary solution while the fotran-based sw is being refactored to use the heap-allocations...